# Help proving / disproving an inequality of sums of positive integers

Tags: inequality, integers

Let $x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n$ and $y_1, y_2,\dots, y_n$ be two sets of positive integers such that $$x_iy_i \leq x_{i+1}y_{i+1} \quad \text{for all } i$$ I need to prove if the inequality $$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right) \cdot \left(\sum_{i=1}^n y_i\right) \leq x_ny_n \cdot n^2$$ holds.

I have tried a proof using induction, that requires the following sub-inequality to hold: $$x_n \sum_{i=1}^n y_i + y_n \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} x_i \leq (2n-1) \cdot x_ny_n$$

If it does not hold, I would be interested in knowing the minimum conditions that would need to satisfy the two sets for the inequality to hold. For instance, if we strengthen the condition to have that $x_iy_j \leq x_ny_n \quad \text{for all } i, j$ then it is easy to show that the inequality does hold.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Try $x_1=1, y_1=99, x_2=10, y_2=10$

Comment: @Henry thanks for the counterexample. Any insight on the minimum conditions that would be needed for the inequality to hold?